# Notice: Undefined index Radio & Textbox

Tags: php, textbox, radio-button

I have created two radio button and the scenario is as below.
1. Non-Dist checked, the textbox should be read-only
2. Dist checked, the textbox enable to fill in

However, I faced and error stated as below when Non-Dist checked and submit the form.

> Notice: Undefined index: cust_edc_code in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\spa317\inv.php on line 49

Please advice what do I missed. Thanks in advance.

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Create SPA Invoice</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post" name="form_spa_inv">
        <table class="tb_create_spa_inv">
            <tr>
                <td>Status* : </td>
                <td>
                    <!--To set status's radio button and save it in database-->
                    <input type="radio" name="cust_status" id="cust_status1" class="status_dis_text" value="Non-Distributor" <?php if (isset($cust_status) && $cust_status=="Non-Distributor") echo "checked";?> />Non-Dist
                    <input type="radio" name="cust_status" id="cust_status2" class="status_dis_text" value="Distributor" <?php if (isset($cust_status) && $cust_status=="Distributor") echo "checked";?> />Dist
                    <!--EDC code for distributor-->
                    <input type="text" name="cust_edc_code" size="10" />
                    <script>
                        $(function() {
                            $('input[class=status_dis_text]').change(function()
                               {
                                   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                       $('input[name=cust_edc_code]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                       $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
                                   }
                               });

                            $('input[class=status_dis_text]:first').attr('checked', 'checked').change();
                        });
                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p style="text-align: center;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    //including the database connection file
    include_once("config_db.php");

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        $cust_status=$_POST['cust_status'];
        $cust_edc_code=$_POST['cust_edc_code'];

        //insert data to database   
        $insert_cust=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_cust(cust_status,cust_edc_code) VALUES('$cust_status','$cust_edc_code')");
    }
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you set `value=""` on the cust_edc_code field?

Comment: @RonaldPK sorry it still show the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input[class=status_dis_text]').change(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('input[name=cust_edc_code]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
        $('input[class=status_dis_text]:first').attr('checked', 'checked').change();
    });
</script>
```

That jquery code seems to disable your input with name 'cust_edc_code', hence it is not getting sent to the server.

If this line isn't doing something really really useful, remove it: 
`$('input[name=cust_edc_code]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

or replace it with this:

```
$('input[name=cust_edc_code]').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `disabled` on an input field prevents it from being sent to the server. If you only want to prevent the user from modifying the field, use `readonly`.

Comment: Your suggestion has done as above code. I have make textbox disable from modifying by user when "non-dist" checked and would like user to modify when "dist" checked. But the problem I faced is when "non-dist" checked and submit the form the error pop up. the readonly will make "dist" unable to modify the textbox How do I solve it? Sorry as I am newbie.